# Pagespeed insights report Analysis

Tags: javascript, html, performance, performance-testing, pagespeed

I am working with page speed insights and I need some help to correctly understand the report of this tool.

**I would like to know clearly what does the report tell me about this work in performance matters**.

This is the report the report that shows low performance score.

[image]

And this is the report that show a better performance score.

[image]

This is according to grunt-pagespeed how does a report looks like:

[image]

I can not see the same report results for those cases. You can see from the sample above it shows values in percentage of optimizations / minifications of files, but in my case I see values like 236,7 for optimizations images or 0.65 for css minifications.

It is not clear to me how to understand the values of this report, although I just improved my page just by looking at the css / html / javascript / css and number of resources called to server, gzip, images etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [Google Pagespeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) and [webpagetest.org](http://webpagetest.org) to make it easy to see what deserves the most attention. Those utilities will be far simpler in determining what's going on with your site at first.

> **This is a waterfall chart.** This gives you a better idea of how resources are processed and loaded on your page, and which resources are taking the longest.

[image: Waterfall network performance chart]

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much I will pay attention to this tool.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I saw this links that actually helps me understand how does the report values works.

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v1/getting_started

It actually explains that results on this reports can come in percentages or values of impact regarding each of this rules that works with this tool:

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rules

http://addyosmani.com/blog/automating-web-performance-measurement-with-psi-for-node/

**So actually in the first report we can see:**

Optimize Images impact is higher than than doing any of the other rules checked for example.

**The second report we can see:**

It is almost the same to try to minimize image sizes or fix rendering blocks in order to have a better performance, both have a value almost of 2.0x

I wrote an article on this: http://jotaoncode.com/blog/news/2015/11/09/page-speed-insights/

Other resources to check for performance are:

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/cDKSlP/jotaoncode.com

http://www.webpagetest.org/

And if you want to see how much your site cost :)

https://whatdoesmysitecost.com/